# Simple Spring Java @Configuration to @Autowire without @Bean

Tags: java, spring, configuration, autowired

I want to make use of spring @Autowired in a java rest project. For the last days, I am trying to set up a simple spring java project with java configuration without explicit bean configuration to check that functionality out. But I can't get it to work. I may be missing something fundamental.

None of the approaches I found in the web and on this site solved my problem so far. I couldn't find a sample for exactly what I'm trying to achieve too. This is mainly due to the amount of different spring versions and approaches spread over the web.

Here is an as easy as I could come up with Java Spring rest sample. I added a few comments with how I interpret spring annotations, as I may err here too:

App base class

```
package restoverflow;

import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;

@ApplicationPath("/")
public class App extends Application {

}
```

Config class

```
package restoverflow;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration  //this is a configuration class and also found by spring scan
@ComponentScan  //this package and its subpackages are being checked for components and its subtypes
public class AppConfig {

}
```

Some Pojo

```
package restoverflow;

public class Pojo {
    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

A service

```
package restoverflow;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service //this is a subtype of component and found by the componentscan
public class PojoService {
    public Pojo getPojo(){
        Pojo pojo = new Pojo();
        pojo.setName("pojoName");
        return pojo;
    }
}
```

And finally a resource where the autowiring of the service should be done

```
package restoverflow;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowire;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("/resource")
@Controller //this is a subtype of component and found by the componentscan
public class Resource {

    @Autowired //this tells to automatically instantiate PojoService with a default contructor instance of PojoService
    private PojoService pojoService;

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Pojo getPojo() {
        return pojoService.getPojo();
    }
}
```

Pom:

```
...
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.7.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.7.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
...
```

I want the pojoService to be instantiated. But I get a NullPointerException.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using Field level injection.

Please go through below link to understand all types of injections:
https://www.vojtechruzicka.com/field-dependency-injection-considered-harmful/

Can't see any clear reason why pojoService is coming null. 
Please check whether pojoService bean is being initialized properly. It might be due to pojoService bean has not been initialized and you are getting null in your controller.

Comment: Thanks for the info on Injection types! As for the pojoService: When I add ```public Resource() {
  System.out.println("pojoService: "+pojoService);
 } ``` It is null. The constructor of PojoService is never called.

Comment: I already mentioned that PojoService bean might not be initialized, that's why PojoService's constructor is not called. Please check whether the component scan is taking care of doing that.

Comment: After adding ```public App () { applicationContext = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(AppConfig.class);`` the PojoService constructor finally is called. But, as mentioned in the comment above, when I call the rest resource, i.e. the resources getPojo method, the service, while being autowired in the resources constructor successfully, still is null.
Edit: The Resource instance on startup does autowire successfully, but when the rest resource is called, that is another instance and does not autowire successfully

Comment: Just give it a try to use setter injection instead of the field injection and check whether that fixes the problem.

Comment: That did not fix it. I made a technology change from spring+jersey to spring boot and it works now. I couldn't come up with a solution to the original problem though.

Answer (score 0):

A `nullpointer` instead of a `NoSuchBeanDefinitionException` is more of an indication that the Spring context is not loaded at all, rather than loaded improperly.

If you're using Spring boot, modify your main class to initialize Spring:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ApplicationPath("/")
public class App extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
    }
}
```

Or else (as the pom.xml snippet did not mention Spring boot), initialize Spring manually by initializing a [`ClassPathXmlApplicationContext`](https://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-auto-scanning-components/) and adding `<context:component-scan base-package="restoverflow" />` in your `applicationContext.xml`.

Comment: It's not a Spring Boot Application, right. It tried ```@ApplicationPath("/")
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
public class App extends Application {
 
 private static ApplicationContext applicationContext;
 
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  applicationContext = 
    new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext();```along with applicationContext.xml in my src folder with ``` <context:component-scan base-package="restoverflow" />``` but that didn't suffice.

Comment: When initializing it within the constructor (it's a webapp) it actually works to set the context and instantiate the beans ```public App () {
  applicationContext = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(AppConfig.class); ``` when I call the rest resource, i.e. the resources getPojo method, the service, while being autowired in the resources constructor successfully, still is null.